# Dump HTML from script

Tags: windows, html, batch-file, vbscript

Is there a way to create a script to download the HTML source to a text for html file locally?

For example, if I wanted to archive the HTML of Google.com each day.

I'm up for batch, VBS or PS1 but preferably BAT or VBS.

I may be using this on many computers so preferably, I'd like a built in script solution only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PowerShell:

```
# $url is the URL you want to download
$url = "http://www.google.com/"

# $path is the location where you want to save the file
$path = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\google.html"

$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile($url, $path)
```

With VBScript:

```
' 'url' is the url you want to download
url = "http://www.google.com/"

' 'path' is the location where you want to save the file
path = "C:\Users\Public\Downloads\google.html"

Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objXMLHTTP.open "GET", url, false
objXMLHTTP.send()

If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
  Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  objADOStream.Open
  objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
  objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
  objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
  Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If objFSO.Fileexists(path) Then objFSO.DeleteFile path
  Set objFSO = Nothing
  objADOStream.SaveToFile path
  objADOStream.Close
  Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

Comment: This should work. It'll be kinda a pain with XP machines, but its a great help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) on your system path, it's a quick one-liner:

```
wget http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html
```

This saves the page locally to the current directory as `bar.html`.

Comment: I looked into this, I should have probably been more clear on the question. I'd prefer a solution that uses no installation so it can be done on computers across a network if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the cleanest solution, but I've used it with success:

1. Download [QtWeb Portable](http://www.qtweb.net/), choose the stand-alone `QtWeb.exe`
2. Then, from the command line you can simply run `QtWeb.exe -dump_and_quit "url" "file"`
3. QtWeb creates a cache and settings folder, so you may want to remove them:

   ```
   rd /s /f QtWebCache
   rd /s /f QtWebSettings
   ```